# How can I get regexp-opt (or similar) not apply on the word with added underscore?

Tags: regular-expressions, syntax-highlighting

See excerpt below for code used in emacs Cadence SKILL mode:

```
(cons (concat "\\<" (regexp-opt '("nil" "t") t)  "\\>")  'font-lock-constant-face)
```

it does a brilliant job at highlighting nil and t.
The issue is that if I have the string " nil_finder " anywhere  within the code, it would highlight the part of the word which is "nil", and keep the _finder not highlighted. I want none of the " nil_finder " highlighted.
I have tried replacing the `t` with `'symbols` or with `'words`, and it did not work.
 I can generate my own (many/ 1 huge) regular expression(s) to get the behavior that I need, but I read the regexp-opt returns a much more efficient regexp.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`\<` and `\>` match *word* boundaries.

Assuming `_` is a symbol-constituent character in the buffer in question, you want to use `\_<` and `\_>` to match the beginning and end of the *symbol*.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Regexp Backslash`

In `rx` syntax, these are `symbol-start` and `symbol-end` respectively.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't that what the second argument to regexp-opt should do?

Comment: If you use `'symbols` then yes, that will wrap the group with symbol boundaries.

Comment: Check `(char-to-string (char-syntax ?_))` for that buffer. `"_"` means it's symbol-constituent.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, you would use `M-:` to enter that elisp expression in the buffer in question; but more simply you could use `C-u C-x =` with point over a `_` character in the buffer in order to get detailed information, which would include the information: `syntax: _  which means: symbol` for a symbol-constituent character.

Answer (score 1):

```
(require 's)  ;; All we need is `s-matches-p'
(require 'rx)
```

Your example:

```
(s-matches-p (concat "\\<" (regexp-opt '("nil" "t") t) "\\>") "nil_finder")
;; t

(s-matches-p (concat "\\<" (regexp-opt '("nil" "t") t) "\\>") "nil")
;; t
```

Fixed:

```
(s-matches-p
 (concat
  (rx symbol-start)
  (regexp-opt '("nil" "t") t)
  (rx symbol-end))
 "nil_finder")
;; nil

(s-matches-p
 (concat
  (rx symbol-start)
  (regexp-opt '("nil" "t") t)
  (rx symbol-end))
 "nil")
;; t
```

Better way:

```
(s-matches-p (rx symbol-start (or "nil" "t") symbol-end) "nil_finder")
;; nil

(s-matches-p (rx symbol-start (or "nil" "t") symbol-end) "nil")
;; t
```

Comment: ``(require 's)  ;; All we need is `s-matches-p'`` - Or you could just use `string-matches-p`...